# Approximation for the number of involutions?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

I am interested any **approximation** that may be available for the following expression:

$$
  {\left(2n\right)}!\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac {1} {2^k \; k! \; \left(2n-2k\right)!}
$$
... which can be expressed more tersely as:
$$
  \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac {{^{2n}\mathrm{C}_{2k}}\;{^{2k}\mathrm{P}_k}} {2^k}
$$
... or alternatively:
$$
  \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac {{^{2n}\mathrm{P}_{2k}}} {2^k\;k!}
$$

... and which actually is the number of involution permutations of $\color{red}{2n}$ objects. I'm interested in moderately large $n$, say $2^{32}$ or more ...

This question originated from trying to figure out the probability that a randomly picked permutation is an involution. I could track it down to $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac {1} {2^k \; k! \; \left(2n-2k\right)!}$ for $2n$ objects, but I was trying to get a feel of how this probability changes as $n$ increases.

I thought of using Stirling's approximation, but I'm not too sure that it won't be misleading given that there are factorials of low values in here as well -- and there is a summation.

Can anyone help? Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

OK, I could find the answer myself ...

It seems what I asked has an actual name -- the number of involutions for $n$ objects is called the [Telephone Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_number_%28mathematics%29) $T\left(n\right)$.

For my question, the number of objects is $2n$, and the answer can be approximated as follows:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac {{^{2n}\mathrm{P}_{2k}}} {2^k\;k!} 
= T\left(2n\right)
\sim
\left(\frac {2n} {e} \right)^{n} \frac {e^{\sqrt{2n}}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt[4]{e}}
$$
... which means that for large $n$, the probability that a randomly chosen permutation of $2n$ objects is an involution is approximately:
$$
\frac {1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt[4]{e}}\left(\frac {e} {2n} \right)^{n} \frac {e^{\sqrt{2n}}}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
Cheers ...

Answer (score 0):

Just note that, you can have a closed form for your sum in terms of the hypergeometric function

> $$ {\left(2n\right)}!\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac {1} {2^k \; k! \; \left(2n-2k\right)!}= {\mbox{$_2$F$_0$}\left(-n,-n+\frac{1}{2};\,\ ;\,2\right)}. $$